# WPF webbrowser control dom change evnt

Tags: c#, wpf, dom, event-handling, browser

I'm trying to find a away to detect if the dom in my WebBrowser control changes.  Is there a way to detect this with an event handler?  Optionally, is there a way to get a javascript event handler to trigger a c# event?  What I am trying to accomplish is to set up a ThumbnailToolBarButton that changes the icon based on the state of and element in the web page ... specifically a play/pause button.  I can toggle the button easily if the user clicks on it directly, but if the user clicks on the pause/play button in the WebBrowser control I want to detect that and toggle the button.  That way it stays in sync no matter which the user clicks.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is some way to communicate from within the browser back to the C# environment.

The `WebBrowser` control has an interesting property called [`ObjectForScripting`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx).  Basically, you can take any "COM-visible" object, and allow the JavaScript environment inside the browser to invoke methods on it.  Once the property is set, the object can be accessed with `window.external` from JavaScript.

To make a class COM-visible, you can just add [ComVisible(true)] above the class declaration.

Comment: That'll do Pig, that'll do. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, that is from Babe ... I'm not calling you a pig. :)